# Array of objects convert to objects sorted by index (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, reduce

I have this array:

```
const list = [{id: 5}, {id: 1}, {id: 4}];
```

i want to achieve this:

```
const result = { 5: {id:5}, 1: {id: 1}, 4: {id: 4}};
```

I tried with reduce, object assign, and it always sorts by id for example:

```
const listById = list => {
 return list.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  const { id } = cur;
  return {
   ...acc,
   [id]: cur,
 };
}, {});
```

};

This sorts by id:

```
{ 1: {id: 1}, 4: {id:4}, 5: {id:5}}
```

but I don't want that.

Comment: it is not possible, because index like keys are sorted. you could add a prefix, then the order of insertation matters.

Comment: It's not possible. Array indicies are always "sorted" in ascending order when iterated over.

Comment: @MihaiAlexandru-Ionut They [are](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58444013) ordered in most situations, but the order is not preserved for array index keys (it's still deterministic, but does not preserve insertion order)

Comment: The only real use case I could see where you want the keys of an object ordered is when you are using `Object.entries`,why not try using a `Map` instead?